# RavenDB and lowercase json serialization - issue while performing query

Tags: json, ravendb, json.net

For me json is lowercase.

So I have defined simple type like this:

```
public class Profile: RootAggregate
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Using ravendb, I can persist it:

```
documentSession.Store(new Profile { Name = "myprofile" });
```

[image]

and then retrieve:

```
var profile = session.Query<Profile>()
                     .Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfNow())
                     .Where(x => x.Name == "myprofile")
                     .SingleOrDefault();
```

which returns... NULL.

If the attribute `[JsonProperty("name")]` wouldn't be there, which results in:

[image]

the query works ok.

How to preserve the attribute and force the query to work as expected ?

Btw: I'm using RavenDB - Build #888

Comment: http://issues.hibernatingrhinos.com/issue/RavenDB-283?projectKey=RavenDB (fixed in build 949)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably an issue in the LINQ query inspector. Please open an issue about it the following link, and if you can, supplying a failing test is the best.

http://issues.hibernatingrhinos.com/issues